# Any more solutions to $m!!-n!=(2^k\pm1)^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Factorial and double factorial

$$m!!-n!=(2^k\pm1)^2$$

Where $m\ge1$ are all odd numbers

$n\ge1$ are all integer numbers

$k\ge0$

**Is there more solution to this equation or this is the only solutions?**

$1!!-1!=(2^0-1)^2$

$3!!-2!=(2-1)^2$

$5!!-3!=(2^2-1)^2$

$7!!-4!=(2^3+1)^2$

$9!!-6!=(2^4-1)^2$

There are infinitely many numbers out there, to save all trouble writing a program for it, can it be straight away answer using maths logic?

Comment: We can be sure m is always odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there more solution to this equation

Yes :
$$5!!-3!=(2^1+1)^2$$

Comment: (+1), is there more after your answer?

Comment: @mahdi: I've been trying to prove that there are no others, but can't, so I don't know.